# Summarize values are not generated after RBreak for Computed Variable while running Proc Report in Base SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create a summary report by Proc Report which should have following columns

```
Probability, Nbr_of_Optys, Total_Media_Value & Tot_Forecast which is computed by the product of probability & Total_Media_Value.
```

I have written this code:

```
 proc report data = Cs1.olympics headline;                                                                                            
   column Probability Stage (n) Total_Media_Value Tot_Forecast;                                                                         
   where Probability > 0;                                                                                                               
   define Probability/group Descending 'Probability';                                                                                   
   define Stage/group noprint;                                                                                                          
   define n / format = comma6. 'Nbr_of_Optys';                                                                                          
   define Total_Media_Value/analysis format = dollar25. 'Tot_Budget';                                                                   
   define Tot_Forecast/computed format = dollar25.;                                                                                     
   compute Tot_Forecast;                                                                                                                
   Tot_Forecast = (Total_Media_Value.sum*Probability)/100;                                                                              
   endcomp;                                                                                                                             

   rbreak after / summarize ol ul skip;                                                                                                 

   run;
```

After running the report a Message is given Missing Values are generated after performing the operation followed by this report

```
Probability Nbr_of_Optys Tot_Budget     Tot_Forecast
100           7          $171,675,000   $171,675,000
90            4          $205,000,000   $184,500,000
70            8          $264,000,000   $184,800,000
50            20         $127,040,000   $63,520,000
30            3          $2,450,000     $735,000
10            319        $333,729,670   $333,372,967
              361        $1,103,894,670
```

I didn't get any summarize value for Tot_Forecast

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, because `rbreak` is executing at the end of the report (as it should), it doesn't have a value for `Probability` to insert in that computation.  Note that `PROC REPORT` in `RBREAK` gives you [according to the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473629.htm):

> the results of the calculations based on the code in the corresponding compute block

Only grouping values can be used.  So `Probability.sum` could be used there, except it's not an analytic variable so it doesn't have a sum; you'd have to add a separate variable with probability in it to use as analytic - but even then it probably doesn't get you what you want.

What you *want*, I think, is the sum of the tot_forecast.  But that's not what you get, unfortunately.  What you need to do is help the `RBREAK` out:

```
proc report data = olympics headline;                                                                                            
   column Probability Stage (n) Total_Media_Value  Tot_Forecast ;
   where Probability > 0;                                                                                                               
   define Probability/group Descending 'Probability';                                                                                   
   define Stage/group noprint;                                                                                                          
   define n / format = comma6. 'Nbr_of_Optys';                                                                                          
   define Total_Media_Value/analysis format = dollar25. 'Tot_Budget';                                                                   
   define Tot_Forecast/computed format = dollar25.; 
   compute tot_forecast;                              
   if upcase (_BREAK_) = ' ' then do; 
     Tot_Forecast = (Total_Media_Value.sum*Probability)/100;    
     tot_forecast_summer=sum(tot_forecast_summer,tot_Forecast);
   end;
   else do;
     tot_forecast=tot_forecast_Summer;
   end;
   endcomp;                                                                                                                             
   rbreak after / summarize ol ul skip;                                                                                                 

   run;
```

What I've done here is create a summation variable `tot_forecast_Summer` which sums the `tot_forecast` values.  Then I use it in the `else` case (when `_BREAK_='_RBREAK_'` technically, but I just compare empty to else for simplicity).  Here we make a different choice in the `compute` statement when the break is on: we set the computed column to the computed sum.   This gives us:

```
Probability Nbr_of_Optys Tot_Budget Tot_Forecast 
100            1        $171,675,000 $171,675,000 
90             1        $205,000,000 $184,500,000 
70             1        $264,000,000 $184,800,000 
50             1        $127,040,000  $63,520,000 
30             1        $2,450,000       $735,000 
10             1        $333,729,670  $33,372,967 
               6      $1,103,894,670 $638,602,967
```